# PHP upload Dom XML with SOAP

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I would like to upload monthly my invoices to a remote server with soap but the upload somehow fails without error message.

I generate the XML file *(the invoice)* with DomDocument from my database. Then I validate it against an XSD and if that returns ok I start the SOAP request.

The documentation for the remote SOAP server says that first I have to call the Authentication service to identify my self and get a session id then I can start the upload. But the Upload doesn't work and I don't get an error message. I'm not familiar with soap so I don't know what to do now.

This is how I do it:

```
$xml = $doc->saveXML(); /*before this is a very long code which creates the XML*/
$xmlauth = new DomDocument();
$xmlauth = loadXML($xml);
if(!$xmlauth->schemaValidate('https://test.e-szamla.hu/apeh_xml.xsd')){
echo 'Error: <br />';
libxml_display_errors(); /*this is a function that formats the error code and saves it to a log file*/
}
else {
    try {
      $trace = '1';
      $url = 'https://test.e-szamla.hu/soap/AuthenticationService.wsdl';
      $client = new SoapClient($url, array('trace' => $trace));
      $params = array(
        'username' => 'hu-0000000x-x-xx',
        'password' => 'XXXXXXX'
      );
    }
    catch(exception $e){
      echo '<h2>Error in connection: </h2>';
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    try {
      $result = $client->startSession($params);
      $_SESSION['sessid'] = $result->sessionid;
      //echo $_SESSION['sessid'];
    }
    catch(exception $e) {
      echo '<h2>Something went wrong:</h2>';
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    try {
    $urlinv = 'https://test.e-szamla.hu/soap/InvoiceService.wsdl';
    $clientinv = new SoapClient($urlinv, array('trace' => $trace));
    $paramsinv = array('sessionid' => $_SESSION['sessid'], 'partner' => 'hu-xxxxxxxx-x-xx', 'xml' => $xmlauth);
    }
    catch(exception $err) {
      echo '<h2>ERROR:</h2>';
      echo $err->getMessage();
    }
    try {
      $resultinv = $clientinv->uploadInvoice($paramsinv);
      echo 'Uploaded with this session id: '. $_SESSION['sessid'];
    }
    catch(exception $err){
      echo '<h2>Something went wrong: </h2>';
      echo $err->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Both the XSD and WSDL URLs are the real URL for the test service and here is a test XML: https://test.e-szamla.hu/samples/dijbekero.xml

And this is the example from the documentation:

**Auth. Service**

```
$client = new SoapClient($url."AuthenticationService.wsdl", array('trace' => $trace));
$params = array(
"username" => "hu-12345678-1-90",
"password" => "12345678"
);
$result = $client->startSession($params);
$_SESSION["sessid"] = $result->sessionid;
```

**Invoice Service**

```
$client = new SoapClient($url."InvoiceService.wsdl", array('trace' => $trace));
$xml = file_get_contents("samples/invoice.xml");
$params = array(
"sessionid" => $_SESSION["sessid"],
"partner" => "hu-00000000-2-00",
"xml" => $xml
);
$result = $client->uploadInvoice($params);
```

How can I make this work or at least get an error message. As you can see I'm passing every required variable like username, password and the partner id and the only thing I have changed is that I doesn't load the XML from file.

Comment: add ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL); at the top of your php and then run it , you should see some error now

Comment: Okay Actually It was there just it was commented out :) and there was a problem with the XML param because it wasn't a string so I changed the $xmlauth to $xml and now there is no more error but the XML is still not uploaded.